# How to display binary image data in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using Lightbox 2 plugin to display lightbox images (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). It works fine, but now my images are all stored as an array of bytes. How can I change this plugin (or maybe use another plugin) to display binary image data rather than a path to an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a custom Image.ashx handler in my ASP.NET MVC app that processes images.